# Closed connection in Grails when using Quartz scheduler

Tags: database, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a Grails application where I have two Quartz jobs running every 10 seconds. It works fine for sometime, but I keep getting the following error after a period of time.

```
[quartzScheduler_Worker-10] ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
Message: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
```

I am trying to understand what is causing the problem.

Here is one of the workers,

```
package noalert
import noalert.NoAlertActivity
import noalert.NoAlertSchedule
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat


class ArchiveJob {
    static triggers = {
      simple repeatInterval: 10000l // execute job once in 10 seconds
    }

    def execute() {
        // execute job
        Map<Object,Object> params = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        def currentTime = new Date()
            def noAlertActivities = NoAlertActivity.createCriteria().list(){
            and{
                lt("stopTime",currentTime)
                eq('state',1)
            }

        }


        NoAlertActivity currentRecord
        for (int i =0; i<noAlertActivities.size();i++){
            currentRecord = noAlertActivities.get(i)
            params.lastActive = currentTime
            currentRecord.delete(currentRecord,params)
        }


        }
    }
```

Could you please let me know the possible cause for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I had this kind of error with my Quartz job was because my JDBC connection got closed (in production). This was fixed by having a better production Datasource configuration. I used the one suggested in [Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/guide/conf.html#dataSource). It will correctly manage the connection pool and create connections if required. Note that this one is for MySQL but it might work for other databases.

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    properties {
       jmxEnabled = true
       initialSize = 5
       maxActive = 50
       minIdle = 5
       maxIdle = 25
       maxWait = 10000
       maxAge = 10 * 60000
       timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
       minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
       validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
       validationQueryTimeout = 3
       validationInterval = 15000
       testOnBorrow = true
       testWhileIdle = true
       testOnReturn = false
       jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
       defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    }
}
```